# Can't enter disk encryption password. (Password field won't focus.)

Tags: boot, encryption

[image: Screenshot]

Whatever I write just ends up in the upper, left corner instead of in the password field. This started when I rebooted after Ubuntu performed an update today.

If I do Ctrl+Alt+F1, I see this:

```
[    0.259413] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1
[    0.259418] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
```

(Ubuntu 16.10, I think)

Edit: One workaraound is to select an older kernel in the boot menu.

Comment: Possibly https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1386005

Comment: Thanks. [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1386005/comments/87) or recovery mode made it possible to boot. However, networking (both wired and wireless) is now unavailable.